# Clearing/truncating a Kafka topic working on linux but not on mac

Tags: bash, apache-kafka

A utility bash function to clear a `kafka` topic by manipulating the *retention* interval is as follows:

```
clearKafka() {
  tname=$1 ;
  kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic $tname --config retention.ms=1000
  sleep 25s;
  kafka-console-consumer.sh  --from-beginning   --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property print.key=true  --property print.value=false --property print.partition --topic $tname --timeout-ms 300 | tail -n 10|grep "Processed a total of"
  kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic $tname --config retention.ms=600000;
  sleep 25s;
  kafka-console-consumer.sh  --from-beginning   --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property print.key=true  --property print.value=false --property print.partition --topic $tname --timeout-ms 300 | tail -n 10|grep "Processed a total of"
}
```

This is a little messy (WARNING's..) but does work on linux - notice the last information that found *0* messages.

```
$ clearKafka airsmall
WARNING: Altering topic configuration from this script has been deprecated and may be removed in future releases.
         Going forward, please use kafka-configs.sh for this functionality
Updated config for topic airsmall.
[2019-05-13 03:11:01,552] ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException
Processed a total of 2000 messages
WARNING: Altering topic configuration from this script has been deprecated and may be removed in future releases.
         Going forward, please use kafka-configs.sh for this functionality
Updated config for topic airsmall.
[2019-05-13 03:11:01,552] ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException
Processed a total of 0 messages
```

The same utility on *mac* ends up with showing 2000 messages even at the very end.

```
Processed a total of 2000 messages
```

And in fact still shows 2000 messages with that command even several minutes later .   So what is the deal on mac for this ? How to clear a topic on mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the command *does* work on Mac .. it just takes much longer: after another few minutes - maybe 5 or 10 minutes total - the topic is showing up as cleared

```
Processed a total of 0 messages
```

Not sure why linux gets it done in a few tens of seconds but mac requires minutes..